# Basic regex help

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match name patters. A name can either be

> lastname,firstname middleinitial

or

> lastname,firstname

i am trying to create a regex to check the last 2 chars of a string are [space][anychar]

I found a tutorial online which says to match A to the end of the string you do

```
 A$

"A" at the end of a line
```

In applying this to mine i was trying to do something like this, and a number of forms of this too. I literally have no idea though :/

```
([\\s][A-Za-z]$)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily check the last two characters without a regular expression.

```
bool hasMiddleInitial = false;
if (name.Length > 1 &&
    name[name.Length-2] == ' ' &&
    char.IsLetter(name, name.Length-1))
{
    hasMiddleInitial = true;
}
```

This is both clearer (more readable) and also executes faster than a regular expression. And it keeps you from having to worry about non-English letters (`A-Z` is a very limited set!).

(P.S. You could also use `char.IsWhiteSpace` instead of directly comparing to `' '`; then it would work with other space characters too. For example, Asian users are likely to enter a U+3000 ideographic space instead of the standard U+0020 space.)

Comment: answered correctly not because you gave code but because i gave up on trying to do it without regex because i didnt no the correct library functions. char.isLetter - could never have known that :D . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the brackets and do it like that: `\s[A-Za-z]$`.

`\s` stands for "any space character", `[A-Za-z]` stands for "any character from this subset: A-Za-z. "A-Z" is something like a keyword for "A to Z diapason", but commonly you use brackets to say something like "any of these symbols". For example, the pattern `[so]` will match any letter which is either **s** or **o**.

You can also do it in reverse by adding `^` symbol after the opening bracket so the pattern matches any character that does **not** occurs in brackets. So `[^so]` will match **a**, **b**, **!** and all other symbols but won't match **s** or **o**.

EDIT: if you're trying to match an initial, "A-Z" might not be the best idea. Use the unicode `\p{L}` property.

Comment: how close was i :D can you tell me for future reference what the brackets do? Thanks

Comment: What if the middle initial is Á? Or Æ? This solution is extremely buggy.

Comment: im not sure the database would allow for that charset anyway? the field type is varchar2(1 byte) if that makes any difference?

Comment: @Timwi Good point. You can use the . to mean 'any character' but you would actually not want to match a 'space' character. So a better regex might be `\s[^\s0-9]$` which means 'a space followed by one character that is not a space or a number in the set 0-9' (assuming you don't want numbers in there!)

Comment: @rik: Then your database schema *also* has a bug; there is very little reason for you to repeat that bug in your code. Otherwise, fixing the bug in future will require two fixes instead of one.

Comment: @ddawber: So you would allow `÷` as a middle initial? And `©`? If you have to use a regular expression, please use `\p{L}` to match a *letter*.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you posted will match any two character string that has a space and a letter.

Meaning:

> A

etc

I'm not sure what you are exactly trying to match so it's hard to comment on what it should be, i can advise you to try a regex development tool to make your life a bit easier.

http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

is one i use (since it's free) but there are a ton out there.

Comment: im tyring to match the last 2 chars of a given string for, [space][any char from a-z]

Answer (score 0):

This

```
/\s[A-Za-z]$/
```

equates to 'match exactly one breaking space and exactly one character from the set A-Z or a-z at the end of the string ($)'.

To test `lastname,firstname middlename` or `lastname,firstname` you would use quantifiers to say 'how many of what should be matched':

```
/^.+,.+\s?.*$/
```

which equates to 'From start of string (^), match any character (.), 1 or more times (+) followed by exactly one comma, followed by any character one or more times followed by zero or one (?) spaces followed by any character zero or more times(*) to end of string ($)'.

Use this as a starting point and build in any required complexity.

Answer (score 0):

These regex should do the trick.
`\w+,\w+(?:\s\w+)?`